# How to call PHP from within JS in PrettyPhoto to include links in descriptions?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, prettyphoto

My WP theme has got a PrettyPhoto lightbox that is used to display the featured image of a project in a portfolio. If i activate it, there is no way to access the project page (with more info/images). I want to be able to open the lightbox and have a button in the description area underneath the image linking to the project page. Right now, the description is being pulled from the description of the image. The code for the link is basically this:

```
<php> echo '<a class="default-link" href="' . $the_project_link . '">'.__("More Details", NECTAR_THEME_NAME).'</a>'; </php>
```

and the part where it should go in the JS code is somehwere in here:

```
pp_descriptions = (isSet) ? jQuery.map(matchedObjects, function(n, i){ if($(n).attr(settings.hook).indexOf(theRel) != -1) return ($(n).attr('title').$('<div/>');) ? $(n).attr('title').$('<div/>'); : ""; }) : $.makeArray($(this).attr('title').$('<div/>'););
```

I'm not good with JS but I know I can't insert PHP directly. What can I do?

Comment: You should check out ajax -> https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

Comment: There is no way to run PHP within JavaScript as PHP is executed on a server.

Comment: I thought that AJAX would be the solution. However I have no idea about the syntax and how to integrate it into my code. Another solution might be having a designated hidden area within the project page with the generated link and have it pulled from there, but again, I have no Idea how to accomplish it in JS...